# How to write a type signature for a block with Sorbet?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I'm currently trying to add types to some core Rails methods, and one of them is [`respond_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to). It can be used with a block, like so:

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @companies }
end
```

The problem I'm having is how to type this exactly, since [the docs on `T.proc`](https://sorbet.org/docs/procs) are pretty minimal. The `format` parameter is an instance of [`ActionController::MimeResponds::Collector`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/Collector.html). There's no need for the block to return anything (e.g. it's not like `Array#select` where it evaluates the block and the block returns a boolean).

I think this is the way you'd want to write the signature?:

```rb
sig do
  params(
    mimes: T.nilable(Symbol),
    block: T.proc.params(arg0: ActionController::MimeResponds::Collector).void
  ).void
end
def respond_to(*mimes, &block); end
```

(We can ignore the `*mimes` argument for now, that's not important)

It seems like this works, but I just want to make sure I'm understanding the way `T.proc` is supposed to be used.

(Note there's [an issue with blocks that are nilable causing a regression to `T.untyped`](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/1243), but that's not what I'm confused on at the moment)

Comment: I've updated the docs to explain this a bit better now :) https://sorbet.org/docs/procs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like correct usage of signatures to me.

BTW, Additions to docs are super welcome!